# how to remove path of my command line?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, path

When I start to enter in different folder the path is registered in my command line and I don't know how to remove it. 
I am almost sure my question wasn't clear. An example is always better.
Once in home:

```
luiz@feynman:~$ cd Music/
luiz@feynman:~/Music$ cd Beatles/
luiz@feynman:~/Music/Beatles$ cd 17\ Love/
```

What is annoying me is this **:~/Music**  or **~/Music/Beatles** before **$**. It seems a stupid problem but when I need to enter into many folders is really a big problem.
I guess I should change something in my .bashrc, but I don't know what.

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic.  But Google for `Bash PS1`.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at and edit the value of `$PS1`. It contains the template for your prompt.

Something like `'\u@\h \w $ ' is typical, in this the '\w' is a placeholder for the working directory. Setting`PS1'\u@\h $ '` would remove the working directory.

For full details on how to set `PS1`, consult the bash man page

Comment: `\W` instead of `\w` will show only the directory you are in

Answer (score 5):

You can use this prompt for `PS1`

```
PS1='\u@\h: $(x=$(pwd); l=${#x}; if [ $l -lt 24 ]; then echo $x; else echo ... ${x: -20};fi;)\$'
```

Just put this at the *very end* of your `.bashrc`. From now every time you go to a path with a length greater than 24 it'll show the last 20 characters preceding by `...`. In fact when we go deep down a directory only the last directories become significant. Because we already know where we started.

Comment: thanks shiplu.mokadd.im, I've already done what  @je4d. But I will try your elegant suggestion latter.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use PROMPT_DIRTRIM to only include the last couple of directories in the prompt.